# how can i parse a json string into nsdictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am writing code for login application. can anyone help me how to parse a json string?
my code is

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSArray *loginDict = [parser objectWithString:loginDict error:nil];

    [loginStatus release];

    [connection release];
```

Comment: You need not to use SBJsonParser just use posted 2 lines will solve your parsing issue.

Comment: Note that json.org lists 5 open source JSON parsers, plus there's the Apple one built into iOS/OSx.  You can pick whichever one you want.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Example data:

```
NSString *strData = @"{\"1\": {\"name\": \"Jerry\",\"age\": \"12\"}, \"2\": {\"name\": \"Bob\",\"age\": \"16\"}}";
NSData *webData = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON DIct: %@", jsonDict);
```

NSLog output:

```
JSON DIct: {
     1 =     {
         age = 12;
         name = Jerry;
     };
     2 =     {
         age = 16;
         name = Bob;
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//*************Static Resopnse
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"text"];
NSLog (@"Content: %@", filePath);
NSString *content = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                 usedEncoding:nil
                                                        error:nil] autorelease];

SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:content];
dictTemp = [json objectWithString:str error:nil];
NSLog(@"Actions is: %@",dictTemp);
NSArray *arr=[[dictTemp valueForKey:@"Data"] mutableCopy];
arrX=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrY=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in arr)
{
    [arrX addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Milestone"]];
    [arrY addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Sites"]];
}   
NSLog(@"X is: %@",[arrX description]);
NSLog(@"Y is: %@",[arrY description]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSLog([[loginStatus JSONValue] description],nil);

//This will give you parsed output.
```

Comment: Seems to me that if he tries that he's going to find that JSONValue is an undefined method.

Comment: JSONValue is not a method of NSString, it is included in a package called SBJson I think... this code won't work out of the box. Better to use NSJSONSerialization as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122534/jsonvalue-arc-issue

Comment: Well, the OP IS using SBJsonParser in his question.

Answer (score -1):

```
   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:  NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   NSlog(@"json String is: %@",responseString);
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
   NSLog(@"Dictionary value is  %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"json"]);
```

the result of this code is:json String is: {"json":{"Success":"Activation code."}}

After Conversation the result is ------- Dictionary value is  {
    Success = "Activation code."};

Comment: What is JSONValue? some category that you've created on NSString?