# JSONValue ARC issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Im trying to use the built in JSON framework in iOS5, but i get an ARC issue when trying to compile this code:

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in iOS5, that doesn't raise an ARC issue?

ARC issue is: **No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'JSONValue'**

Comment: `NSString` does not have a method `JSONValue` maybe you have been using a category on `NSString`... is it imported? If not you need to look at [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. You were right, i needed to look at the NSJSONSerialization class.

Comment: this is what u want [Instead of Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782053/nsarray-returning-string-instead-of-dictionary)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The message you get means 'There is no method `JSONValue` declared in `NSString`' (which is absolutely true). In order to use the built in JSON serializer try this one:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

Ps For options see the documentation on [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Also note that results can be an `NSArray` as well.